# thttpd directing all routes?

Tags: http, routes, thttpd

I'm hosting a Flutter app with thttpd via Docker.

I'm trying to understand how I can catch all routes, as there doesn't seem to be a configuration and I don't want to go down the Nginx way.

For example domain.com/some-route should load the index, but it does not :-/

```
FROM alpine:3.16.0

# Install thttpd
RUN apk add thttpd

# Create a non-root user to own the files and run our server
RUN adduser -D static
USER static
WORKDIR /home/static

COPY ./build/web/ /home/static

# Run thttpd
CMD ["thttpd", "-D", "-p", "8080", "-d", "/home/static", "-u", "static", "-l", "-", "-M", "60"]
```

Comment: thttpd is very literal when it comes to serving content. What configuration do you think you have configured to show a default page?

Comment: Some kinda -route="catchAll" or something would be nice.